# How to show both normal and Chinese calendar in CollectionView in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to make an iOS app by Swift like this picture to show user both of calendar. The top one is the date of the normal calendar and the other is the equivalent date of the Chinese calendar. My problem is that I only show the date of the normal calendar and don't know how to show the other one. So anyone has the idea to do this please tell me.

[image: Calendar in the app]

Comment: Thank for your helping. I done to show the date of normal calendar. Problem is that i dont how to show the equivalent date of chinese calendar in cell

Comment: A `Date` is just a moment in time. To get to day, month and year, you have to interpret it through a `Calendar`. Initiate a `Calendar(identifier: .chinese)` and pass it the `Date` value.